# Delphi Livebindings - Including other field values in CustomFormat

Tags: delphi, livebindings

This should be simple, but I appear to be struggling to get it to work.

Quite simply I have a name column and an id (autoinc) column, I'd like to combine the two fields into one label control using Live Bindings.

I've set the custom control to

"%s (Self.Owner.FieldByName('ind_id').Text)"

But to no avail, I simply says 'Name 0' were 0 is supposed to be the field ID value.

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong!?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could always use a calculated field to combine the 2 fields

Comment: Did you try without `Owner`: `%s (Self.FieldByName('ind_id').Text)`?

Comment: Without owner just results in a 'FieldByName' not found error. A caculated field just seemed a bit OTT, although it would work, I thought LiveBindings was supposed to do this easily.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Self.DataSet.FieldByName('ind_id').Text